# 403 error when deploying a Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, heroku

Earlier, I was getting the following error (from the Chrome console) when trying to open a Node.js app using Heroku:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://browser-rpg-app.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This was accompanied by a 403. I managed to fix it by adding this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Now the first error is gone, but I'm still getting a 403. I can run the app flawlessly on `heroku local web`, but not when I actually deploy. Here's what the log says:

```
2019-12-02T22:41:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-12-02T22:41:32.617542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-12-02T22:41:36.786903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484013+00:00 app[web.1]: ForbiddenError: Forbidden
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484062+00:00 app[web.1]: at SendStream.error (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:270:31)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484066+00:00 app[web.1]: at SendStream.pipe (/app/node_modules/send/index.js:553:12)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484068+00:00 app[web.1]: at sendfile (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1103:8)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484071+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.sendFile (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:433:3)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484074+00:00 app[web.1]: at index (/app/routes/index.js:9:9)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484077+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484079+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484081+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484083+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-12-02T22:42:00.484085+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2019-12-02T22:42:00.482239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=browser-rpg-app.herokuapp.com request_id=845c8d30-4ca7-44f4-ab69-ae312e722b1b fwd="68.174.27.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=403 bytes=380 protocol=https
```

As you can see, there's no helpful message or explanation, it just says forbidden. I really have no clue what the problem could be, but here's a bunch of important/relevant files:

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const configRoutes = require("./routes");
const static = express.static(__dirname + '/public');
const app = express();

app.use("/public", static);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());

configRoutes(app);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("The application is running on http://localhost:3000");

    if (process && process.send) process.send({done: true});
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "browserrpg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.2",
    "angular-route": "^1.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": (git url here, removed for privacy)
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

In case it's relevant, here's the "/" route that Heroku calls:

```
const index = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..\\public\\html", "index.html"));
    return;
}
```

And here's the constructor that sets up all the routes:

```
const constructorMethod = app => {
    app.get("/", index);
    app.get("/game", gameGet);
    app.post("/game", gamePost);

    app.use("*", (req, res) => {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" });
    });
  };
```

Here's my file structure as well:

```
BrowserRPG
│   README.md
│   Procfile
|   app.js
|   mongoCollections.js
|   mongoConnection.js
|   package.json
|   settings.json
│
└───data
    │   enemydata.js
    │   gamecalc.js
    |   gamedata.js
    |   index.js
    │
│   
└───public
    │   
    └───css
        |   main.css
    |
    └───html
        |   game.html
        |   index.html
    |
    └───js
        |   angular.js
        |   angularActiveGame.js
|
└───routes
    |   index.js
```

I'm also using a mongodb database, but I don't think that's causing the problem, considering that I haven't even attempted to connect it to Heroku yet, and you don't need to have a db running to get to the first page of the app. Is there something here that might be causing the error? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the route imported as configRoutes(app) and not as app.use('/', configRoutes)?

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't entirely remember, I wrote a lot of the route stuff over a year ago. I vaguely remember having issues getting app.use to work, but I'm not quite sure. I edited my question to include more info on the routes. Is there a major difference between configRoutes(app) and app.use('/', configRoutes)?

Comment: One is correct for sure as per documentation and the other one I have never seen it.  Try writing that part of the code again as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, the solution was actually annoyingly simple. In my "/" GET route, the path contains a `..`, which was being viewed as malicious, and therefore rejected. I changed it to this:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(appRoot, "public/html", "index.html"));
```

`appRoot` is a global variable that points to the root directory of the application. Hopefully this helps someone who may be having a similar issue.